# How can I initElements on multiple classes?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests

I have one class :

```
public class PageFactoryInitialization {
    public MainPageObjectAction mainPageObjectAction = 
        PageFactory.initElements(
            Driver.webDriver, 
            MainPageObjectAction.class
        );
}
```

I have all the `@FindBy` elements in `MainPageObjectAction` and I have this class which extends `PageFactoryInitialization`.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MainPageObjectStep extends PageFactoryInitialization {

    @Step("Enter page")
    public void doAction() {
        Driver.webDriver.get("https://staging1.ogrcrew.com");
        Driver.webDriver.manage().window().fullscreen();
        Driver.webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(
            10, 
            TimeUnit.SECONDS
        );
        mainPageObjectAction.menuMainNavigation.click();
        mainPageObjectAction.acceptCookies.click();
        mainPageObjectAction.menuMainNavigation.click();
    }
...
```

How can I avoid

```
public MainPageObjectAction mainPageObjectAction = 
    PageFactory.initElements(Driver.webDriver, MainPageObjectAction.class)
```

for every class that page object models.

I tried various stuff but I encounter NullPointerException errors.

Comment: Did you try the constructor approach? You can initialize the parent class( PageFactoryInitialization ) at the time when you create a new page object.

Comment: because  the methods are in @Step + void method somehow this is not working ; without extending the class I didn't find any possibility

Answer (score 0):

```
public MainPageObjectAction mainPageObjectAction1;

public PageFactoryInitialization(MainPageObjectAction mainPageObjectAction) {

    mainPageObjectAction = PageFactory.initElements(Driver.webDriver, MainPageObjectAction.class);

}

@Before
public void beforeTest() {
    login = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class );
}
```

public void initElements() {
       MainPageObjectAction mainPageObjectAction = PageFactory.initElements(Driver.webDriver, MainPageObjectAction.class);
   }

```
   List<Class> init = new ArrayList<>();
   init.add(MainPageObjectAction.class);

   PageFactory.initElements(Driver.webDriver, init);



@Override
public <T> MainPageObjectAction getPage(Class<T> page) {
    return PageFactory.initElements(Driver.webDriver, MainPageObjectAction.class);
}

public static <T> T getPage1(Class<T> page) {
    return PageFactory.initElements(Driver.webDriver, page);
}
```

This is what I have tried so far; nothing work NullPointerException , only with extension of class it works